# How to convert my For loop into sequential execution

Tags: shell, background-process, for

I wrote the following `for` loop (spread over multiple lines here for better readability):

```
for F in CLEAN_READS/*_1.fa; do
  R=${F%_*}_2.fa; BASE=${F##*/};
  SAMPLE=${BASE%_*};
  metascript assembly -1 $F -2 $R -o folder_${BASE%_*} &
done
```

When I run the loop all scripts are started in parallel. How can I change the loop to start the scripts in sequential order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that you included a `&` at the end of your command, which sends the command to the background and immediately passes on to the next.

The loop should behave as you intended when you remove that `&`. Note that instead you must put a `;` to end this instruction (when placing it all on one line, as originally posted), otherwise the shell will produce an error message.

Also, as pointed out by Stéphane Chazelas, you should make a habit of quoting variable expansions (where approproate, which is in most places); a good introduction can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).

Comment: Probably also worth noting that the OP also forgot to quote their parameter expansions (assuming they used a POSIX shell like `bash`).

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me..and I learned about the role of &

Comment: You can also mix and match, for example to use 4 processors at a time effectively. GNU has a parallel package that will maintain concurrent streams of process requests, starting a new one to replace those that complete. (Caution: there may be more than one package with similar names.)